# Nifi pass attribute through process groups

Tags: apache-nifi

Here is my summary setup, just to give you an idea of what im after:

[image]

What I want do is use updateattribute to set a few attributes, for example:

```
demo = 1
```

I'm able to pick up this attribute within the Test 1 group, but I can't pick it up in the Test 2 group. Is there a way to pass the attribute through both groups?

Comment: Connect the relation `success` with UpdateAttribute and test1, again UpdateAttribute and test2. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @Lamanus Sorry that is just an example, they are all connected on success on my actual project. It still doesn't make it across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **`some processors`** in NiFi where attributes are getting lost, probably you are using some processor in `Test2` processor group causing this issue.

To workaround this issue use **`Put/Fetch distribute cache processor`** to store the attributes **before passing flowfile to the processor** (where attributes are getting lost) then **`fetch from cache`** after the processor.

Please refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/188338/attributes-lost-after-running-selecthiveql.html) link I have add **`sample flow`** and **description** how to resolve this issue.